# How to break through the bedrock ceiling in the nether

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-redstone

I need to break a block of bedrock in the ceiling of the nether so that I can make farms on the ceiling. I don't want to use command blocks or creative mode. I need to do it in survival mode.

Comment: You can't build above the nether on Bedrock Edition.

Comment: Did you check? On my phone, I was able to....

Comment: @Eristheguest did you just try it or are you recalling that off of your head, because unless they changed it recently I don't think you can

Comment: I remember checking on the BETA 1.17 on my phone. It worked.

Comment: @Eristheguest I have just tried and when I try to place blocks it says “height limit for building is 128 blocks”

Answer (score 2):

You can’t build on the ceiling when you attempt to build this is what happens:
[image: Height limit for building is 128 blocks]

Comment: Hmm. I may have a modified copy, because that ISNT what happens to me. Or some weird bug, I dunno

Comment: 1.17 messes with world heights, so it might be possible to build above Nether when the actual 1.17 release is available.

Answer (score 0):

i remember you used to be able to break through it with trees, but you need to find a space that is empty right below the roof that has a block under said empty space, place a ladder in the empty space and pearl to the ladder. you should be able to clip through the block on top by going up.